# Why pyspark fillna does not fill boolean values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, fillna

I have a dataframe with a boolean column and I want to fill the missing values with False.

However, when I use fillna method, nothing happens:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(True,), (True,), (None,), (None,)], ['col'])
df.fillna(False).show()
```

The output is

```
+----+
| col|
+----+
|true|
|true|
|null|
|null|
+----+
```

But when I do it manually, the values are filled in:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as fn
df.withColumn("col", fn.when(fn.col("col").isNull(), False).otherwise(fn.col("col"))).show()

+-----+
|  col|
+-----+
| true|
| true|
|false|
|false|
+-----+
```

Does anyone know why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fillna for Boolean columns were introduced in Spark 2.3.0. I suppose you're using an older version of Spark, which does not support Boolean fillna yet.

See the docs for [Spark 2.2.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna) and [Spark 2.3.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna) respectively to check the differences.

The way to fix is either to upgrade your Spark version, or to use your code. Another way is to use `coalesce`, e.g.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn("col", F.coalesce(F.col("col"), F.lit(False)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. Passing it as a dictionary works:

`df.fillna({"col" : True})`

This PR helped me, especially the comment : https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/17688

[image]